# displaying date format in a customaized way

Tags: php, date

I have the following date:

```
2014-09-26 11:30:00
```

I need to display it in the page like:

```
26-September-2014 At 11:00
```

I have the following code to do this:

```
$exp_datetime = date('d-F-Y At H:s', strtotime($exp_datetime)); // So stupid I know ;)
echo "Visit Date: " . $exp_datetime;
```

and I get the following result:

```
Visit Date: 26-September-2014 AM30 11:00
```

I need to know how can i get the required result!

Many many thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your "At" word. Because, as described here: http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.format.php "A" and "t" are reserved characters.

So your correct code should be:

```
$exp_datetime = date('d-F-Y \A\t H:s', strtotime($exp_datetime));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$exp_datetime = date('d-F-Y At H:s', strtotime($exp_datetime));
                             ^
```

`At` is not an accepted date format character. You can do like

```
echo "Visit Date: ". date('d-F-Y', strtotime($exp_datetime));
echo " At ". date('H:s', strtotime($exp_datetime));
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also use strftime() in this case:

```
echo strftime('%d-%B-%G At %H:%M', strtotime('2014-09-26 11:30:00'));
// 26-September-2014 At 11:30
```

Answer (score 1):

Also using `datetime`

```
$d = new DateTime('2014-09-26 11:30:00');
echo $d->format('d-F-Y \A\t H:s');
```